(Unity 2022.3.25f1) Игра крашится если нажимаю на некоторые кнопки
Во время создания платформера я перешел к этапу UI. Сначала я хотел сделать выигрышное меню после прохождения уровня. Но в самом конце я столкнулся с проблемой. На этом меню есть 3 кнопки: Меню, рестарт и след. уровень, но 2 последних кнопки крашут игру и в редакторе, и на билде. Причем Unity не выявляет никаких ошибок.
Вот код который я использовал для кнопок:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void LoadScene(int scene)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(scene);
    }

    public void RestartScene()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }

    public void Quit()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }

    public void SetTimeScale(float timeScale)
    {
        Time.timeScale = timeScale;
    }
}

Параметры в OnClick:

Menu - LoadScene(0)
Restart - RestartScene()
Next Level - LoadScene(3)

Помимо всего кнопка Main menu перезапускает сцену...

Код, который вы приводите, должен работать. По описанию похоже на то, что вы не добавили все сцены в File->Build Settings....

Нужно зайти в File->Build Settings... и, если сцен нет в списке, то  добавить их туда в правильном порядке.

Учесть, что сцена под индексом 3 - это четвертая по порядку сцена в этом списке, не третья.



Проблема только в том, что как минимум редактор крашиться не должен. Он должен выдать сообщение в консоль о невозможности загрузить сцену. Если описанным выше проблема не решилась, попробуйте посмотреть логи Unity
